# How do I `yum localinstall` from my `yum search` result?

Tags: software-installation, yum, rpm

I'm trying to install some dependencies for `thrift` using `yum`. I've found, for example boost via `yum search boost` which gives me (after a load of fails as the PC not on the web, but has a local repository somewhere...on the network...I think):

`boost.x86_64 : The free peer-reviewed portable C++ source libraries`

But when I go to try `yum localinstall boost*` I get nothing '*file does not end with RPM, skipping*', likewise `find boost*` gives nothing.

Should my yum command work, and this is a sign that it's not on the network? Or is it on there and I'm not using the right command to find the path to the rpm for it? *Bottom line:* How can I use yum to install a local file I found using `search`?

#### Edit:

I should mention, running `yum install boost*` fails as I cannot get on the web. This still leaves me wondering: The `yum search` result is not local (as per Ignacio's [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48977/how-do-i-yum-localinstall-from-my-yum-search-result/48981#comment68419_48981)), and it's not installed (`whereis` and `which` are drawing up blanks, as is `locate`) nor can I even reach a repo. So what is `yum search` finding, and how do I install it?

Comment: What is the output of `locate boost.x86_64`?

Comment: @terdon `locate: cannot stat () '/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db': No such file or directory`

Comment: Run `updatedb` as root first, and then then the `locate` command. `locate` will search for file names containing a pattern. It should at least be able to find your local rpm.

Comment: @terdon updated and it finds nothing. How do I know the search result is local?

Comment: I assumed it was local because you used `localinstall` and were referring to a local package.

Comment: @terdon I was hoping to. Regardless, `search` found somnething...what was it?

Comment: search probably found it in your LAN repository. That is not a local file, it is on the network. Local refers to files on you _local machine_ not your local network.

Comment: @terdon so how do I find and install that then? Surely there must be an option to display the path of objects that search returns!

Comment: Have you tried Ignacio's solution below? If `yum search` can find it `yum install` should be able to install it. To avoid the globbing problem, you could also try `yum install boost.x86_64`

Comment: @terdon I have yes. It's found by `search` but not `install`. I even tried the full name: `boost.x86_64`

Comment: Try clearing yum's cache and then do a search again: `yum clean all; yum search boost`

Comment: @terdon *that* fails flat out: 'Could not recieve mirror list...'. So it looks like I need to transfer the files the hard (read, long-winded) way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localinstall` is intended to install packages you have on your local filesystem. If yum finds it in a repository then you should use `install` instead.

**EDIT:**

The reason `yum install boost*` fails is because you have files that match that pattern, and your shell is globbing it. Escape the wildcard.

```
yum install 'boost*'
```

Comment: Two things, does the out put form the `search` call imply it's not local (i.e. in a repo) and two, if it is in a repo, why doesn't just using `install` work?

Comment: yum *only* looks at packages either in a repo or already installed. And nowhere do you say that `install` doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that to start.

Comment: +1 as I foudn this useful. Also I've updated the question. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Escaping the wildcard doesn't work either; it tries the all the mirrors, they all fail, it tries to download form base, that all fails (why does it get this far?) Then tells me all the files in boost didn't install.

Comment: Marking as accepted as, three years on, I'm never going to be able to test this...but it looks like it's useful.